# How to send mail from gitlab after pipeline build

Tags: build, gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, sendmail

After completion of pipeline committer get a mail from gitlab of its success or failure with all information like committer, branch, commit, Project etc. But only committer is receiving this mail.

Now, How to send this mail to other members of gitlab or to the common DL along with committer.
Where we can set this in gitlab? Is there any setting which needs to enabled?

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by completion of pipeline? Do you mean jenkins job or something else in your pipeline?

Comment: Using gitlab CI/CD to build the pipeline not Jenkins. So as soon as the pipeline completed(either pipeline will successful or fail), its trigger one mail to committer about it. I want to add some other recipient to that.

Answer (score 2):

On left hand side panel
Project --> Setting --> integrations -->Pipelines emails

Tick active checkbox and add recipients then save the changes.

[image]